# Problem in Generalized Binomial coefficient

Tags: combinations, binomial-coefficients

consider the following example:
$$ \left(1+x\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}=\sum_{k=0}^{∞ }   {{\frac{1}{2}}\choose{k}} \cdot x^k={{\frac{1}{2}}\choose{0}}x^0+{{\frac{1}{2}}\choose{1}}x^1+{{\frac{1}{2}}\choose{2}}x^2+...=
$$$$\frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)!}{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)!(0)!}x^0+\frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)!}{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)!(1)!}x^1+\frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)!}{\left(-\frac{3}{2}\right)!(2)!}x^2+...$$
as it's clear here we have two negative factorial,but why we have this error?

now look at this one which is just a substitution:

let $a=1/2$, then we have: 
$\left(1+x\right)^{a}=\sum_{k=0}^{∞ }  {{a}\choose{k}} \cdot x^k={{a}\choose{0}}x^0+{{a}\choose{1}}x^1+{{a}\choose{2}}x^2+...=\frac{(a)!}{(a)!(0)!}x^0+\frac{(a)!}{(a-1)!(1)!}x^1+\frac{(a)!}{(a-2)!(2)!}x^2+...=1+ax+\frac{a\left(a-1\right)}{2}x^2+...$$

substitute back $a=1/2$ 
 finally $=1+\frac{1}{2}x-\frac{1}{8}x^2+...$

this answer true but actually it depends on the first one , so the question is why the first one does not give the true answer?

Comment: @Grothendeck, you may see my article at MSE  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3262143/a-kindergarten-of-binomial-coefficients

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending Dr Zafar Ahmed DSc'a answer,
since
$\binom{p}{k}
=\dfrac{\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(p-j)}{k!}
$,

$\begin{array}\\
\binom{\frac12}{k}
&=\dfrac{\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(\frac12-j)}{k!}\\
&=\dfrac{\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(1-2j)/2}{k!}\\
&=\dfrac{\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(1-2j)}{2^kk!}\\
&=(-1)^k\dfrac{\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(2j-1)}{2^kk!}\\
&=(-1)^{k+1}\dfrac{\prod_{j=1}^{k-1}(2j-1)}{2^kk!}\\
&=(-1)^{k+1}\dfrac{\prod_{j=1}^{k-1}(2j-1)\prod_{j=1}^{k-1}(2j)}{2^kk!\prod_{j=1}^{k-1}(2j)}\\
&=(-1)^{k+1}\dfrac{\prod_{j=1}^{2k-2}j}{2^{2k-1}k!(k-1)!}\\
&=(-1)^{k+1}\dfrac{(2k-2)!}{2^{2k-1}k!(k-1)!}\\
&=(-1)^{k+1}\dfrac{(2k)!}{2^{2k-1}k!(k-1)!(2k-1)(2k)}\\
&=(-1)^{k+1}\dfrac{(2k)!}{2^{2k}k!^2(2k-1)}\\
&=\dfrac{(-1)^{k+1}\binom{2k}{k}}{2^{2k}(2k-1)}\\
\end{array}
$

$k=0 \to 1,\\
k=1 \to \dfrac{\binom{2}{1}}{2^2\cdot 1}
=\dfrac{1}{2},\\
k=2 \to \dfrac{\binom{4}{2}}{2^4\cdot 3}
=-\dfrac{6}{48}
=-\dfrac{1}{8},\\
k=3 \to \dfrac{\binom{6}{3}}{2^6\cdot 5}
=\dfrac{20}{320}
=\dfrac{1}{16}\\
$

Note:
none of this is original.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to calculate binomial co-efficients is $${p \choose k}=\frac{p(p-1)(p-2)...(p-k+1)}{k!},$$ where $p$
is not essentially an integer. So ${p \choose 0}=p$, ${p \choose 1}=p$, ${p \choose 2}=p(p-1)/2$ and so on. Then ${1/2 \choose 0}=1, {1/2 \choose 1}=1/2, {1/2 \choose 2}=-1/8, {1/2 \choose 3}=1/16...$ and so on.

Comment: based on the definition ${p \choose k}=\frac{p!}{k!\left(p-k\right)!}$, here with this definition can you tell me how did you calculate ${1/2 \choose 1}$?

Comment: @Grothencheck, Simple as ${p \choose 1}=p% and ${p \choose 2}=p(p-1)/2$ so on and so forth even if $p$ is non integer.

Comment: See my answer for an alternate expression.

Comment: @marty cohen, Yes I liked it and gave {+1}, well done.

Comment: @marty cohen, you may see my article at MSE   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3262143/a-kindergarten-of-binomial-coefficients